# display objects algorithm

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

I have array of graphic icons. Every Icon has property level and time. I need to create graphic representation of this icons by some rules.

Every icon with same time should be in same column.

They have to be in columns sorted by levels in groups by ten. For example icon with property level 5 and property level 6 will be in first column in first and second row. Icons with level 11 and 12 with diferent time will be in second column but in 3th and 4th row.

```
EXAMPLE:
time           1    5    7
group 10-19  icon      icon
-            icon
group 20-29       icon icon
-                      icon
group 30-39  iconX
```

In example above iconX have property level 35 and time property 1.

I have been thinking a lot of time about it but really dont know how to solve it?

Do you have any idea how to solve it ? What should be best practice for this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First separate your icons in one array per column (time). Then paint each column and give `y` to each icon depending on the level. It could as simple as ìcon.y = icon.level * 10`. Done.

Comment: I didn't see the problem. Separate the array based on time column and sort each based on group attribute. What's the result data structure do you expect?